# Why am I getting a AggregationCursor as a result and not an average?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm querying my MongoDB database and don't understand why I am getting an aggregator cursor as a result when I expect to be returned a single number. Maybe I need to get something from the cursor object? Just can't figure out what.

```
module.exports = CalculateAvg = async collection => {
try {
  // const count = await collection.countDocuments({ word: "Hello" });
  // console.log(count) // logs 140, which shows that it is accessing the db correctly
  const cursor = await collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { word: "Hello" } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        mean: {
          $avg: "$value" // in the dataset, each doc has a value field which equals a number
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
  console.log(cursor) // logs a large AggregationCursor object, rather than a number
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
  };
```

Comment: Try `cursor.eachAsync(function(error, doc) {console.log(doc);});`

Comment: @Valijon thanks for the recommendation but that gave me the following error `TypeError: cursor.eachAsync is not a function`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) return value is `aggregateCursor`, I recommend checking the [Mongo's Nodejs driver types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongodb/index.d.ts) file whenever you're not sure whats the return value or the parameter value for any of these functions is.

You want to use [cursor toArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray) like so:

```
  const cursor = await collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { word: "Hello" } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        mean: {
          $avg: "$value" // in the dataset, each doc has a value field which equals a number
        }
      }
    }
  ]).toArray();
```

Comment: The question uses `_id: null` which means they want a single document back, so returning an array adds extra work to then get the object out of the array.  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68198207/13273704) by Jesús Sánchez solves this problem by using `.next()` instead.  Additionally, that link to Mongo's Nodejs driver types is no longer functional.

Answer (score 1):

You should use next() method... For Example

```
const pipeline = [{
      $facet: {
        total: [{
          $count: 'createdAt'
        }],
        data: [{
          $addFields: {
            _id: '$_id'
          }
        }],
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$total'
    },
    {
      $project: {
        data: {
          $slice: ['$data', skip, {$ifNull: [limit,'$total.createdAt']} ]
        },
        meta: {
          total: '$total.createdAt',
          limit: {
            $literal: limit
          },
          page: {
            $literal: ((skip/limit) + 1)
          },
          pages: {
            $ceil: {
              $divide: ['$total.createdAt', limit]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }];

const document = await collection.aggregate(pipeline);
const yourData = await document.next();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!  `.next()` prevents the extra step of having to access the return object inside of an array like `.toArray()` necessitates.