# How to get all categories with count of item related to each category in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have `posts` collection like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "644584a36f72fad9366e2cfb"
  },
  "title": "test",
  "description": "sample",
  "categoryName": "misc",
  "categoryId": "643d76f4ce4b765e18dee084",
  "categoryImage": ""
}
```

Category collection:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "643d76f4ce4b765e18dee084"
  },
  "categoryName": "misc"
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "643d76f4ce4b765e18dee085"
  },
  "categoryName": "aws"
}
```

I want to get all the categories with total count in each category

Example: `misc` category may have 3 posts and `aws` category with 2 posts

so I am looking at:

```
[
   { categoryName:'misc', categoryId: '12345678' count: '3' },
   { categoryName:'aws', categoryId: '12345678' count: '2' },
]
```

How do I achieve this in mongo?

Comment: so can categories have 0 cout as well. what i mean is can i use the posts collection only. if every category have at least 1 post you can just use post collection otherwise need to combine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I assumed that there are categories without posts. So therefore some categories must get count as 0. If it is not the case it is straightforward with a group on the posts collection only.
Anyway you can lookup the posts collection and get the post list for each category. Then in the projection the count is essentially the `$size` of the `postList`

```js
db.category.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "posts",
      let: { category_id: { $toString: "$_id" } },
      pipeline: [ { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$categoryId", "$$category_id" ] } } } ],
      as: "postList"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      categoryId: { $toString: "$_id" },
      categoryName: 1,
      count: { $size: "$postList" },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p6Dvp7k0fRD)

for completion here is the other case when each category has a post

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$categoryId",
      categoryName: { $first: "$categoryName" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      categoryId: "$_id",
      categoryName: 1,
      count: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LM3FTo6LEkl)

Comment: Its returning `<ref *3> AggregationCursor {` instead of data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029239/why-am-i-getting-a-aggregationcursor-as-a-result-and-not-an-average can u check if this help